# WPF Dynamic TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl with dynamically created tabs and content that vary depending on the XML that is passed in but, I also need a couple of TabItems to be created regardless of the XML content. When I add a `<TabItem Header="Users"/>` I receive a Items Collection must be empty before using an ItemsSource. Here is what I have now:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Content}">

                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="Header"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="Tab Content"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>                   
            </TabControl>
```

Is there anyway to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the error, you must choose between either data binding the `ItemsSource`, or setting the `Items` property - you can't do both. You could use a `CompositeCollection` to combine the contents of the dynamic tabs with another collection containing the non-dynamic tabs. You can then bind the `ItemsSource` to this `CompositeCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CompositeCollection to achieve the desired functionality.
This might be helpful(though it talked TreeView here) -
[Binding to a single element inside a CompositeCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826672/binding-to-a-single-element-inside-a-compositecollection)