# TabControl with two data bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` that I want to have 2 data bindings. One is to have a `TabItem` for each item in a list and another single `TabItem` that is a *Summary* and uses an `ItemsControl` to show a template of controls for each item in another list.

I can set a `TabControl` to either one of these two types of data binding but not both of them at the same time. How could I get a TabControl to do both?
Could I somehow add an extra `TabItem` to the `TabControl` that has `ItemSource`, `Binding` set? Then I could load the new extra `TabItem` with XAML.

Comment: I think it'll be an interesting idea. And can you use code or Xaml to abstract the purpose you want? If so, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you just add the summary `TabItem` to the `List<TabItem>` that is being bound to? In theory that should show all the different items in the `TabView`

Answer (score 0):

### Expose a Combined Collection

You can expose a collection in your view model that combines both the collection and the addtional item like below (if you do not modify the collection, you can also use any other enumerable type).

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MyViewModel()
   {
      var myTabItemCollection = // ...get the items collection.
      var mySummaryTabItem = // ...get the summary item.

      TabItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(myTabItemCollection)
      {
         mySummaryTabItem
      };
   }

   public ObservableCollection<MyTabItemViewModel> TabItems { get; }

   // ...other properties, methods, ...
}
```

### Using a Composite Collection

There is a dedicated `CompositeCollection` type for combining one or multiple collections and single items in XAML. However, this type has [severe shortcommings in terms of data-binding](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b15cbd9d-95aa-47c6-8068-7ae9f7dca88a/collectioncontainer-does-not-support-relativesource?forum=wpf). It does neither derive from `FrameworkElement`, nor is it a `Freezable`, which  makes it very difficult, cumbersome and error-prone to work with. I will present one solution with this type for the sake of completeness. Let's assume this view model:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ObservableCollection<MyTabItemViewModel> TabItems { get; }

   public MyTabItemViewModel Summary { get; }

   // ...other properties, methods, ...
}
```

In theory this would be easy if `CompositeCollection` **would be** to data-bindable (this does **not** work):

```
<TabControl>
   <TabControl.ItemsSource>
      <CompositeCollection>
         <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding TabItems}" />
         <TabItem DataContext="{Binding Summary}"
                  Header="{Binding}"
                  Content="{Binding}" />
      </CompositeCollection>
   </TabControl.ItemsSource>
</TabControl>
```

In order to make it work, your can apply various approaches like in these related questions:

- [How do you bind a CollectionContainer to a collection in a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6446699/6181599)
- [CompositeCollection + CollectionContainer: Bind CollectionContainer.Collection to property of ViewModel that is used as DataTemplates DataType](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19243109/6181599)
- [Binding to a single element inside a CompositeCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826672/binding-to-a-single-element-inside-a-compositecollection)

As an example, I will use a [binding proxy](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) type to enable binding inside `CompositeCollection`. It will bind to the `DataContext` of the `TabControl` and expose it with the `Data` property. Since the proxy is a resource, the `CompositeCollection` can refer to it as source for binding with `StaticResource`.

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
   <TabControl.Resources>
      <local:BindingProxy x:Key="TabControlBindingProxy" Data="{Binding}" />
   </TabControl.Resources>
   <TabControl.ItemsSource>
      <CompositeCollection>
         <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Data.TabItems, Source={StaticResource TabControlBindingProxy}}" />
         <TabItem DataContext="{Binding Data.Summary, Source={StaticResource TabControlBindingProxy}}"
                  Header="{Binding}"
                  Content="{Binding}" />
      </CompositeCollection>
   </TabControl.ItemsSource>
</TabControl>
```

This will also work for multiple collections and single items, but be aware that this and the other approaches from the related questions - *although they compile and run just fine* - might crash the Visual Studio designer, which is unfortunate. Consequently, I recommend you to take the approach of exposing a combined collection, which is more reliable, easier to comprehend and simple.