# WPF TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate - binding to object with different child collections

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am trying to bind a collection to wpf `TreeView` control using data templates. Each item(Person) in the collection also contains two different collections(Cars, Books) of type car and book.

Here's simplified list of the objects involved to save space.

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name
  public List<Book> Books;
  public List<Car> Cars;
}

public class Book
{
  public string Title
  public string Author
}

public class Car
{
  public string Manufacturer;
  public string Model;
}
```

Here is how I am binding

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.treeView1.ItemsSource = this.PersonList();
    }

    public List<Person> PersonList()
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();


        Book eco = new Book { Title = "Economics 101", Author = "Adam Smith"};
        Book design = new Book { Title = "Web Design", Author = "Robins" };

        Car corola = new Car { Manufacturer = "Toyota", Model = "2005 Corola"};
        Car ford = new Car { Manufacturer = "Ford", Model = "2008 Focus"};

        Person john = new Person { Name = "John", Books = new ObservableCollection<Book> { eco, design }, Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car> { corola } };

        Person smith = new Person { Name = "Smith", Books = new ObservableCollection<Book> { eco, design }, Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car> { ford } };

        list.AddRange(new[] {john, smith });
        return list;
    }
```

Here is the Xaml code

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView  Name="treeView1">
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

I am looking to see the tree display to look like this.

```
>John
  >Books
    Economics 101 : Adam Smith
    Web Design    : Robins
  >Cars
    Totota : 2005 Corola
>Smith
  >Books
    Economics 101 : Adam Smith
    Web Design    : Robins
  >Cars
    Ford: 2008 Focus
```

this sign  `>`  is used to show the tree folder and should not be considered in the template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a bit complicated since your tree has two different child collections. WPF does not support a scenario with multiple `ItemsSource` definitions. Therefore you need to combine those collection into a [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx). The type matching of the composite elements (i.e. Car, Book) will be done automatically.

In XAML you need to define so-called [HierarchicalDataTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) that match your type definitions. If `local` points to the namepace where `Book`, `Car` and `Person` are defined, the simplified `HierarchicalDataTemplates` could look like this:

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding CompositeChildren}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Book}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Model}" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Then you need to hook up your collection to the tree control. There are a few possibilities to do this, the easiest would be to define a property in your `Window` class and define a Binding:

```
<TreeView Items={Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=Persons}/>
```

This should point you into the right direction, but don't take my code as compile ready :-)

Answer (score 3):

`CompositeCollection` is a good answer, except you can't bind the child collections to the `DataContext` because it's not a `Freezable`.  You can only bind them to resources.  (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189052/why-is-compositecollection-not-freezable) for more on that.)  That makes it kind of hard to use in a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, since the `ItemsSource` in one needs to bind to a property in the current context to be useful.

If you don't need change notification on the collections, you can easily implement a property in your view model, e.g.:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Items
{
   get { return Books.Concat(Cars); }
}
```

If you need change notification on the collection, it's a lot less trivial.

Comment: As my entities are based on an XSD, I can't really create a CompositeCollection. But the generated code from the XSD is partial, so I could insert a IEnumerable!

Answer (score 1):

You need a `DataTemplate`, otherwise WPF doesn't know how to display your object.

Comment: Could you help me with the tempate design?