# How to show class hierachy in WPF TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchy

I have some simple hierarchy in my WPF project.

I have base class, which calls Product. Then I inherit two classes from this base class. Then I inherit couple more classes from both of them.

So I have Product class, then Book and Disk classes, which inherit from Product class, and RecipeBook class, ProgramingBook class and AdventureBook class, which inherit from Book class.

Then I create  collection and add some book there like collection.Add(new RecipeBook() {bla bla bla});

Finaly I have collection with diferent classes.

So all I need is to show all this stuff via WPF TreeView.

It's gonna be smth like that:

```
Product
    Book
       RecipeBook
          Book#1
          Book#2
        ProgramingBook
          Book#1
        ....
    Disk
      Disk#1
      Disk#2
      .....
```

So how can I do that?

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" Height="224" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="337" >
      <TreeViewItem Header="Products" >
          <TreeViewItem Header="Books">
              <TreeViewItem Header="Recipe"></TreeViewItem>
              <TreeViewItem Header="Programing"></TreeViewItem>
              <TreeViewItem Header="Adventure"></TreeViewItem>
          </TreeViewItem>
          <TreeViewItem Header="CDs">             
          </TreeViewItem>
      </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: almost nothing. i don't know even how to start that. i've already read a lot, but didn't find anything I need on google

Comment: Are you able to add nodes to a WPF Treeview? did you create a WPF applocation? how does the xaml with the treeview look like?

Comment: I tried to add nodes, but it seems like I need to create own class, inherit it from TreeView or TreeViewItem, and only then I'll be able to add childs to the tree.

Comment: isn't there a property called something like ItemSource? what does it happen if you assign a collection of strings to such property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this most of the way there (i.e. the groupings work but all groups must have the same level.)

```
Product
    Book
       RecipeBook
          Book#1
          Book#2
        ProgramingBook
          Book#1
        ....
    Disk
        Disk
          Disk#1
          Disk#2
      .....
```

I am using your sample data as my input so my class structure is as follows:

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Book : Product
{
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}

class RecipeBook : Book
{
    public int NumRecipes { get; set; }
}

class ProgrammingBook : Book
{
    public string LanguageCovered { get; set; }
}

class Disk : Product
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

populated as follows:

```
ObservableCollection<Product> products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        products.Add(new ProgrammingBook() { BookName = "P1", LanguageCovered = "C#" });
        products.Add(new ProgrammingBook() { BookName = "P2", LanguageCovered = "F#" });

        products.Add(new RecipeBook() { BookName = "P3", NumRecipes = 4 });
        products.Add(new RecipeBook() { BookName = "P4", NumRecipes = 6 });

        products.Add(new Disk() { Size = 512 });
        products.Add(new Disk() { Size = 1024 });

        this.DataContext = products;
```

We need a groupoing by type so we can use a converter on the CollectionViewSource PropertyGroupDescription.

This is my converter (I pass in different values for different levels of the hierarchy for the type:

```
public class GroupByType : IValueConverter
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (type == "root")
        {
            if (value is Product)
            {
                return "Product";
            }

            return null;
        }

        if (type == "subs")
        {
            if (value is Book)
            {
                return "Book";
            }
            if (value is Disk)
            {
                return "Disk";
            }
        }

        if (type == "main")
        {
            if (value is ProgrammingBook)
            {
                return "PBook";
            }
            if (value is RecipeBook)
            {
                return "RBook";
            }
            if (value is Disk)
            {
                return "Disk";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

once we have the data we need appropriate templates (mine are simple and are shown in the xaml at the end) but we need some way of choosing them so I use the following template selector:

```
public class Selector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string templateKey;
        if (item is CollectionViewGroup)
        {
            if ((item as CollectionViewGroup).Name == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            templateKey = "GroupTemplate";
        }
        else if (item is ProgrammingBook)
        {
            templateKey = "pTemplate";
        }
        else if (item is RecipeBook)
        {
            templateKey = "rTemplate";
        }
        else if (item is Disk)
        {
            templateKey = "dTemplate";
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        return (DataTemplate)((FrameworkElement)container).FindResource(templateKey);
    }
}
```

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="pTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LanguageCovered }"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="rTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NumRecipes}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Size}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <c:GroupByType x:Key="gt" />
    <c:Selector x:Key="s"/>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding}" x:Key="cvs">
                    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription>
                <PropertyGroupDescription.Converter>
                    <c:GroupByType type="root"/>
                </PropertyGroupDescription.Converter>
            </PropertyGroupDescription>
            <PropertyGroupDescription>
                <PropertyGroupDescription.Converter>
                    <c:GroupByType type="subs"/>
                </PropertyGroupDescription.Converter>
            </PropertyGroupDescription>
            <PropertyGroupDescription>
                <PropertyGroupDescription.Converter>
                    <c:GroupByType type="main"/>
                </PropertyGroupDescription.Converter>
            </PropertyGroupDescription>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}, Path=Groups}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource s}"/>
</Grid>
```

The idea here is that for each type in your hierarchy we create a new group with the actual objects being the leaf nodes of the tree.  You can add as many levels to the grouping as you need by adding new sections to the converter.  You can also rename the groups by changing the return value of the converter.

If you have any questions then please ask as this is quite a long answer :).

Comment: Give me a few minutes to tidy it up and zip it up.  Most of the code is in the answer though.

Comment: yep, it works! thank u very much! now I need understant how it works... :) 'cause most of this shit I've never seen in my life :)

Comment: You can find ClassHierarchyTreeViewSample.zip here (for vs2010).  http://bit.ly/kJTUeu

Comment: No problem - thats quite a bespoke grouping so not something you will use every day :).

Answer (score 1):

check: [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx), there is a complete example for you to start: [Displaying Hierarchical Data Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771440%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you for the link, but I have diferent situation. in msdn example for every class there is only one list of diferent class. but in my situation i have few lists for every class..

Comment: i mean for Product list I need to keep two Lists inside - Books list and CDs List. In Books list I need to keep 3 lists. But as I know, I can set only one ItemSource for every template

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298979/wpf-treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-binding-to-object-with-different-child-co

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out [Josh Smith's article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) on using the TreeView with MVVM