# How to dynamically generate MenuItems using x:Reference?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, .net-4.0, contextmenu

I have a MenuItem whose ItemsSource is set to the following CompositeCollection:

```
<CompositeCollection>
    <MenuItem x:Name="SpinnerMenuItem" Header="Waiting..."/>
    <CollectionContainer 
        Collection="{Binding DataContext.Source, 
                     Source={x:Reference SpinnerMenuItem}, 
                     Converter={StaticResource NoOpConverter}}"/>
</CompositeCollection>
```

The breakpoint inside my NoOpConverter is telling me that my collection is successfully getting bound to the CollectionContainer.  The problem is, the menu is showing up completely empty! All I get is a popup about 3 pixels high and 10 pixels wide.

**Why are my menu items not being displayed?** Even the "SpinnerMenuItem" disappears once the bound list is populated. I was not having this issue in the simpler case, when I was just binding to a CollectionViewSource static resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with CompositeCollection. The workaround is to use a StaticResource instead of a Binding or similar. More info here: [Why is CompositeCollection not Freezable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189052/why-is-compositecollection-not-freezable)